How to Prove This Elegant Integral Identity Involving Trigonometric and Square Root Terms
Let $ a $, and $ b $ be real numbers. Show that:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\left(\sqrt{1 + (a \cos t + b \sin t)^2} + a
\cos t + b \sin t\right)^2}{1 + \left(\sqrt{1 + (a \cos t + b \sin
t)^2} + a \cos t + b \sin t\right)^2} \, dt =
\arccos\left(-\frac{b}{\sqrt{1 + a^2 + b^2}}\right). \nonumber
\end{equation}
I have been trying to prove this integral identity but have encountered some challenges. Here is the reasoning I have followed so far:
Trigonometric substitutions: I attempted to simplify the term $ a \cos t + b \sin t $ using the identity $ r \cos(t - \phi) $, where $ r = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} $ and $ \phi = \arctan(b/a) $. This seemed natural, but it led to complicated expressions in terms of $ t - \phi $, and I couldn't make significant progress.
Change of variable: I considered a change of variable to take advantage of the symmetry of the interval $ [0, \pi] $, but it wasn’t clear how to simplify the square root in the numerator.
Relation to the arccos function: I suspect that the result involves some key property of trigonometric functions and their relation to the arccos function, but I am unsure how to connect this to the integrand.
This problem seems intriguing because it combines definite integrals, trigonometric terms, square roots, and inverse functions, suggesting there is an elegant simplification underlying it. I would appreciate any guidance on how to proceed or if there is a technique I might be overlooking.

Use mathjax to type equations & maths symbols, link: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and approach zero website link( to avoid asking duplicate questions) link, https://approach0.xyz/search/

@myplayaplay Are you sure the upper limit of the integral shouldn’t be $2\pi$? Integrating over a full period would make dealing with the phase offset easier.

The integral is indeed defined up to $\pi$, not $2 \pi$. While integrating over a full period might simplify handling the phase offset in periodic functions, the specific problem is set with an upper limit of $\pi$. To confirm its correctness, I tested the integral numerically using particular values for the parameters $a$ and $b$, and the results align perfectly with the analytical prediction: $\arccos\left(-\frac{b}{\sqrt{1 + a^2 + b^2}}\right)$

Very often, it is advantageous to transform an expression like $a \cos t + b \sin t$ into : $c \cos(t-\alpha)$ where $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\alpha = \arctan(\tfrac{b}{a})$

Note that
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{1 + (a \cos t + b \sin t)^2} + a
\cos t + b \sin t\right)^2}{1 + \left(\sqrt{1 + (a \cos t + b \sin
t)^2} + a \cos t + b \sin t\right)^2} \\
=\frac12\bigg(1+\frac{a \cos t + b \sin t}{\sqrt{1 + (a \cos t + b \sin
t)^2} } \bigg) \\
$$
Then
\begin{align}
I=& \ \frac12\int_0^\pi \bigg(1+\frac{a \cos t + b \sin t}{\sqrt{1 + (a \cos t + b \sin
t)^2} } \bigg) dt\\
=&\ \frac\pi2 +\frac12\int_0^\pi \frac{d(a \sin t - b \cos t)}{\sqrt{1+a^2+b^2 - (a \sin t - b \cos t) ^2} } \\
= &\ \pi - 
\cos^{-1}\frac{b}{\sqrt{1 + a^2 + b^2}}= \cos^{-1}\frac{-b}{\sqrt{1 + a^2 + b^2}}
\end{align}

$\displaystyle +1$. As usual, you get a simple answer.

WOW! Thank you so much! :)

Let $x = a\cos t + b \sin t = r \sin(t+c)$ where $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, $\sin c = a/r$, and $\cos c = b/r$. After some algebraic manipulations, we can simplify the integrand considerably:
$$
\frac{(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x)^2}{1+(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x)^2} = \frac12\left(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right).
$$
The integral of the first term is simply $\frac\pi2$. The integral of the second term is
$$
\frac12\int_0^\pi \frac{r\sin(t+c)}{\sqrt{1+r^2 \sin^2(t+c)}}~dt = \frac12\int_{-b}^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+r^2 - y^2}}~dy = \int_{0}^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+r^2 - y^2}}~dy,
$$
where I substituted $y=r\cos(t+c)$. The antiderivative of the integrand is $-\arccos\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\right)$, so the integral is
$$
\int_{0}^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+r^2 - y^2}}~dy = -\arccos\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\right) + \frac\pi2.
$$
Therefore, the full integral evaluates to
$$
\pi - \arccos\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\right) = \arccos\left(-\frac{b}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}\right).
$$
